# Java 8 Number of messages on Azure service bus queue

Tags: java, azure, maven, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I want to get the number of messages on an Azure servicebus queue in Java 8. I tried a couple of things but when I want to import these libraries, my Maven can't find the right libarys(jar) like it seems:

```
import com.microsoft.azure.credentials.ApplicationTokenCredentials;
import com.microsoft.azure.management.Azure;
import com.microsoft.azure.management.servicebus.Queue;
import com.microsoft.azure.management.servicebus.ServiceBusNamespace;
import com.microsoft.rest.LogLevel;
```

What library I need and do you have a helloWorld example to get the number of messages on a queue with Java ?

Untill now I have this, but my import all gives errors:

```
ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(clientId, domain, secret, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
Azure azure = Azure.configure().withLogLevel(LogLevel.NONE).authenticate(credentials).withSubscription(subscriptionId);

ServiceBusNamespace serviceBusNamespace = azure.serviceBusNamespaces().getByResourceGroup(resourceGroupName, namespaceName);
Queue queue = serviceBusNamespace.queues().getByName(queueName);
int messageCount = queue.inner().messageCount();

System.out.println("Message count: " + messageCount);
```

Anyway is this code ok ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the below **java** code, I am able to get the number of messages on an Azure service bus queue in **Java 8**.

I created a new **java, maven** project with **java 8** in my environment as below:-

[image]

**Code:**

```java
import com.microsoft.azure.AzureEnvironment;
import com.microsoft.azure.credentials.ApplicationTokenCredentials;
import com.microsoft.azure.management.Azure;
import com.microsoft.azure.management.servicebus.Queue;
import com.microsoft.azure.management.servicebus.ServiceBusNamespace;
import com.microsoft.rest.LogLevel;

public class ServiceBusQueueExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String clientId = "<your_client_id>";
        String domain = "<your-tenant_id>";
        String secret = "<>your_client_secret>";
        String subscriptionId = "<your_subscription_id>";
        String resourceGroupName = "your_resource_group_name";
        String namespaceName = "<your_servicebus_name>";
        String queueName = "<your_queue_name>";

        ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(clientId, domain, secret, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
        Azure azure = Azure.configure().withLogLevel(LogLevel.NONE).authenticate(credentials).withSubscription(subscriptionId);

        ServiceBusNamespace serviceBusNamespace = azure.serviceBusNamespaces().getByResourceGroup(resourceGroupName, namespaceName);
        Queue queue = serviceBusNamespace.queues().getByName(queueName);
        long messageCount = queue.inner().messageCount();

        System.out.println("Message count: " + messageCount);
    }
}
```

**Dependencies:**

```java
<dependencies>
     <dependency>
          <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
          <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
          <version>1.41.4</version>
     </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Make sure to assign **role assignment** for the **client application** as **owner** ,

[image]

In the Azure portal, **I have 10 messages in my ServiceBus Queue** as below:-

[image]

***It ran successfully and gave the number of messages count on an Azure service bus queue. Refer below:-***

**Output:**
[image]

**Reference:**
Check this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-queues?tabs=passwordless) to know more about sending messages to Azure Service Bus.